# compile and join coffeescript files

Tags: coffeescript, cakefile

I have the following structure:

```
/lib
  / myfile.js.cofee
  / secondfile.js
/src
```

and i would like to compile them into

```
/lib
  / myfile.js.cofee
  / secondfile.js
/src
  / awesomefile.min.js
```

I have read about Cakefiles, but i'm not sure how to exactly do this.

Thanks,
Mike

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you happen to be using something based on connect (e.g. express), I'd recommend using [connect-assets](https://github.com/TrevorBurnham/connect-assets). If not, then [grunt](http://gruntjs.com/) may be a good bet, as was previously suggested. If you'd like to do this yourself using a `Cakefile`, here is one approach you could use:

Note that the convention is to build from src to lib (which is the reverse of what you stated in the question). I'll use that convention below, but you can easily switch it back if needed.

`$ npm install snockets`

place the following in `src/awesomefile.coffee`:

```
#= require secondfile.js
#= require myfile.js.coffee
```

create a `Cakefile` with the following:

```
fs = require 'fs'
Snockets = require 'snockets'

NAME = 'awesomefile'
INPUT_FILE = "src/#{NAME}.coffee"
OUTPUT_FILE = "lib/#{NAME}.min.js"

task 'build', 'Build lib/ from src/', ->
  snockets = new Snockets()
  js = snockets.getConcatenation INPUT_FILE, async: false, minify: true
  fs.writeFileSync OUTPUT_FILE, js

task 'clean', "remove #{OUTPUT_FILE}", ->
  fs.unlinkSync OUTPUT_FILE
```

Now you can just do:

`$ cake build`

and that will create a `lib/awesomefile.min.js`.

You can have the files in `src` track their own dependencies, or you can list the order to be included in a single file like I've done above. For more, you can check out the [snockets](https://github.com/TrevorBurnham/snockets) repository. Also note that the [compiling chapter](http://arcturo.github.com/library/coffeescript/05_compiling.html) chapter of [The Little Book on CoffeeScript](http://arcturo.github.com/library/coffeescript/) is a good resource for learning about cake files.

Comment: i am compiling from src to lib. I clearly didn't explain it thoroughly enough. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Might not be the exact answer you expected.

Grunt.js at www.gruntjs.com is a very helpful buildtool and certainly includes a lot of stuff that you need to do on a daily basis with a webproject.