# How to set up reusable modular CoffeeScript project

Tags: node.js, coffeescript, requirejs, amd, javascript

I have [a CoffeeScript project (called jAddressParser)](https://github.com/brianmhunt/jAddressParser) that I am hoping to turn into reusable module. Unfortunately I am not overly familiar with how to modularize CoffeeScript for such a purpose, while maintaining sensible interoperability with an existing project.

The [project in question parses address strings](https://github.com/brianmhunt/jAddressParser) - [no short order](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16413), to be sure. However for the purpose of the project I am working on, this strategy should work and it is possible someone else may benefit from it and perhaps others may make some useful contributions. Everybody wins!

So what I have is code laid out in a directory like this:

```
/
  README.md
  LICENSE
  package.json
  /src
    main.js
    main.coffee
    canada.coffee
    iso3166.js
  /test
  /build
```

In an ideal world, my workflow would be like this:

1. Test the above javascript from the command line. I would think [Node.js](http://nodejs.org/) is the most suitable way.
2. Compile the files in `/src` to a `/build/jAddressParser.js` file. I would think [r.js](https://github.com/jrburke/r.js/) would work well for this.
3. When all is ready, copy the `jAddressParser.js` from the `/build` to my web project.
4. Include the jAddressParser in my web project with the appropriate `requirejs` call (i.e. it would be AMD-ready) e.g. `require(['jAddressParser'], -> ...)`

Since it seems I have to include the dependencies (lodash, requirejs, require-cs, XRegExp, CoffeeScript) I expect I will do this by putting specific versions in the `/lib` directory or by using git submodules (though submodules seems to be a bit of overkill for such a small project).

I have never created a reusable CoffeeScript module, and I was essentially unable to find a good reference on how to perform the same for a web-module (there seem to be some decent examples for projects that are node.js-only - thought I would certainly love to see a list of more). I would be quite grateful for any thoughts or references that may shed light on the viability of the proposal above, or how you yourself might go about organizing such a project?

Comment: Maybe my answer to [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13050060/compile-and-join-coffeescript-files) question would be helpful.

Comment: @DavidWeldon: That's a helpful guide. I have done [something similar](https://github.com/brianmhunt/jAddressParser/blob/master/Cakefile), but with [coffee-toaster](https://github.com/serpentem/coffee-toaster).